# sitecore default language when creating new items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to set up sitecore so that when users create new items, they get created in a certain language (en-AU). I've set the 'contentLanguage' to that language, and when createing anything in the content tree, it does indeed create it in that language. However, if they go to create a a template or anything like that (outside the content tree), it still creates it in 'en'. Is there a web.config setting somewhere to set this so that ANY items created is created in 'en-AU'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to implement an event handler or pipeline processor to copy whatever you're creating in the language you're in and auto-populate it into the `en-AU` language. Here's a blog post with sample code:

[Copying Sitecore Items across Languages](http://geekswithblogs.net/amaniar/archive/2010/10/25/copying-sitecore-items-across-languages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a default language for new items using the `contentLanguage` setting on the `shell` site definition in the web.config. It's located under:

```
<sitecore>
    <sites>
        ...
        <site name="shell" contentLanguage="en-AU" ...
```

Comment: This is what I thought - and it works for content items that are in the 'content' node, but it doesn't work anything that is in any of the other nodes, such as 'layouts'.